# There is no error but favor page does not appear

Tags: flutter-layout

the favor page does not apper , no errors but it does not work , i do the same for the top app bar and it works , please advice me and thanks .  ( i add the 2 pages ,categories ,favorites , sorry i add more words to solve the question issues ........................................................................ )

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:meals/categeory_screens.dart';
    import 'favorties.dart';
    
    class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
       TabsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
    }
    
    class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
      final List _pages=[
        CategoreyScreen(),
        FavortiesScreen(),
    
      ];
    
      int _select =0;
    
    void _selectedPage(int index){
      setState((){
    index=_select;
    });}
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title:const Text('meals'),),
    
          body:_pages[_select],
    
          bottomNavigationBar:
          BottomNavigationBar(
            onTap: _selectedPage,
            selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            items: [
    
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
    
               icon: Icon(Icons.category),
           label: 'categories'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem( icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                label: 'favor'),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
    
    
    
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
 _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with 
WidgetsBindingObserver {
  int _selectedTabIndex = 0;

  _changeIndex(int index) {
     setState(() {
      _selectedTabIndex = index;
      print("index..." + index.toString());
  });
 }



 List _pages = [
   CategoriesScreen(),
   FavorScreen(),
];

 @override
 void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
 }


 @override
 void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
 }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    body: Container(),
    bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
    ),
  );
 }


  Widget get bottomNavigationBar {
return Container(
   
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedTabIndex,
        onTap: _changeIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 12,
        unselectedFontSize: 12,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.appColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[500],
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedTabIndex == 0
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.local_mall,
                    size: 22.0,
                    color: Colors.appColor,
                  )
                : Icon(
                    Icons.local_mall_outlined,
                    size: 22.0,
                    color: Colors.colorBlack100,
                  ),
            label: "Categories",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedTabIndex == 1
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.dashboard,
                    size: 22.0,
                    color: Colors.appColor,
                  )
                : Icon(
                    Icons.dashboard_outlined,
                    size: 22.0,
                    color: Colors.colorBlack100,
                  ),
            label: "Favor",
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
    ));
   }
  }
```